# Аналоги ОТРС

Tags: php, sql

Подскажите аналоги OTRS http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTRS
Есть ли что-то похожее на пхп? Нужно, чтобы систему можно было подключать к сайтам с разными бд и отвечать обрабатывать тикеты.

Answer (score 1):

У OTRS есть свой [HTTPS REST, есть SOAP](http://www.otrs.com/otrs-help-desk-software-supports-rest/?lang=ru) . И взаимодействовать с OTRS можно написав код на любом удобном Вам языке.
А простейшие интеграции выполняются легко без малейшего представления о перле или на чем там OTRS написан. 
Например, делал следующее:
- подсасывал несколько сторонних баз пользователей с логинами, паролями и описаниями
- в информационном окошке о пользователе размещал ссылку, которая вела на страницу пользователя в CRM

Лично для меня OTRS безальтернативен, т.к. он бесплатен и при этом имеет самый гибкий и мощный функционал вкупе с долгой историей и активной разработкой.

Answer (score 0):

Их много, мы используем [redmine.org](http://redmine.org), например, для тикетов и [tortoisesvn.net](http://tortoisesvn.net) для синхронизации исходников. Вполне удобная комбинация, с лихвой покрывает все требования.

Comment: нет это не то. redmine к тому же на руби и это система для работы с проектами и задачами. нужна просто платформа для обработки тикетов саппортом и интеграцией со своим сервисом через апи если оно есть

Answer (score 0):

Ищите свою идеальную систему здесь:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: Я разве говорил, что мне нужно идеальная система???? Я спросил, есть ли что-то похожее на пхп.

Answer (score 0):

[itop](http://www.combodo.com/spip.php?page=rubrique&id_rubrique=8)